# Show widget outside sidebar - WORDPRESS

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using a theme total made by me. I need to show [Sidebar Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sidebar-login/) plugin's widget in header.

I tried this in header.php:

```
<div class="login"><?php the_widget('sidebar-login');?></div>
```

Page load without error and I have a space occupied by that div, but there is nothing inside. Maybe it is because I insert no $instance and no $args after $widget, but I don't know what they are.Maybe i need specific code for the plugin i linked.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao Michele,
are you trying to use [Sidebar Login plugin from Mike Jolley](https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/sidebar-login/)?

According to [the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget), **the_widget** method wants the plugin Class Name, not the namespace, your code should work if you use something like this:

```
<?php the_widget('Sidebar_Login_Widget');?>
```

If you are using a different plugin you have to check the correct class name in php code.

Comment: Solved !! Thanks a lot !   Grazie amico :)